# How to create a switch form in Symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

For my project in symfony I need to create a certain form. The Entities and Controllers were not an issue but now that it comes to the form and view file I am stuck as to how to approach this. I am using twig and would like to use the Symfony forms.

```
   | Option A | Option B | Option C |
-------+----------+----------+----------+
Type A |     x    |     x    |     x    |
-------+----------+----------+----------+
Type B |     x    |     x    |     x    |
-------+----------+----------+----------+
Type C |     x    |     x    |     x    |
-------+----------+----------+----------+
```

The `x` represents a checkbox. Using this form the user can select a different amount of options for each Type. The types are stored in an entity as are the options.

How would i do something like this the Symfony way?

### Edit

What I want to to is to get the results from the `Type` entity and the results from my `Option` entity. The `Type` entity will supply the rows for a table and the `Option` entity will supply the columns. Each row will have a checkbox under every column. This is so that I can select multiple options for each type.

I need to build a form from both these entities and I can't figure out how to approach this issue.

Comment: Doc for the form conponent :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html.

Comment: Doc for the ChoiceType : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html

Comment: I know how to use forms. Just not this particular case with dynamic form items.

Comment: What is dynamic ? How does it work ?

Comment: What you need is form theming. The already mentioned documentation explains how you can write a theme for your form. You'll likely write a table for your form and single rows (`<tr>`) for each type.

Comment: Form collections are what you need: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html. Link only comments are so much fun.  And if you really need a different number of choices for each entity then you get to explore form events: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html.  Form events are in fact a good argument for ditching the form component and just writing something that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [bundle](https://github.com/infinite-networks/InfiniteFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/checkboxgrid.md) . I never use it but has a pretty good reputation.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Link only answers are strongly discouraged and will probably end up getting down voted.  Perhaps you could update your answer with a list of specific items that you feel your linked bundle directly addresses.